# SQL Server 2008 - Temporary table issue

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a temporary table to get some some data to make a report that I was asked for in Crystal Report. Date is a parameter I'm gonna be using to order later on in the report, but I'm using this code:

```
create table #reptemp
(
    Empresa varchar(100),
    Servicio varchar(50),
    Total int
) 

insert into #reptemp(Empresa, Servicio, Total) 
   select
       RazonSocial, TipodeServicio, TotalaPagar 
   from dbENC46 
   where Fecha >= '2014-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
     and Fecha <= '2015-06-31 23:59:59.999'
```

And I'm getting this message:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Can someone help me see why this is happening?? I'm not using any kind of 'datetime' data type, so I don't understand where is my mistake

Comment: What is the dataType of `Fecha`?

Comment: Also, in addition to the complexity of choosing the right number of days in a month, please see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx) for other reasons why you want to use `< beginning of next range` instead of trying to find `<= end of current range`.

Comment: the datatype is datetime, but my mistake was in my date, i was adding an extra day to June

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not able to resolve the date `'2015-06-31 23:59:59.999'` you put into the `where` clause, because the month of June has only 30 days not 31. ;)